# Can I mute a friend on Foursquare?

Tags: foursquare, mute

Is there a way to not get notified when a certain user checks in?

They somehow manage over 500 points a day, checking into "somewhere" every few minutes, and it's creating too much noise in my notification center.

Without unfriending, how can I mute them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At [foursquare.com](https://foursquare.com), if you go to the user profile for that user, there is a drop-down that lets you set the notifications you receive from that person.

[image: Foursquare notifications]

Simply set that to "Off" instead of "Always On" or "Nearby" and you should be good to go.

---

On my Android, if I go to the "Profile & History" for one of my Foursquare friends, there's a button directly under their photo that looks like a vibrating smartphone.

Tapping that brings me to the "Push Notifications" screen, which tells me what notifications I'm getting from the person, with a button labeled "Set push notifications".

Tapping that button gives me the option to see what notifications I get from that person:

- Off
- Nearby
- Always

Same as above.

(I expect the iPhone version of the app is very similar.)

Comment: Actually I do have that icon on the iPhone. I misunderstood and thought it was saying they're nearby me.